# Only re-run the failed job in a GitHub Actions matrix

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

How can I re-run only a failed job in a GitHub Actions matrix?

I only want to run the failed jobs and not all of them. My CI matrix takes a lot of time to run, and I don't want to waste energy re-running the whole matrix because one of them failed.

So this button is not my solution:

[image: No Re-run all jobs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub finally made it possible to do this. There is now a "Re-run failed jobs" button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Re-run a specific job has not been implemented yet, [but it is on the roadmap](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/271).

However, reading [this ISSUE](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/432) about the subject, there is a workaround from [this post](https://github.community/t/ability-to-rerun-just-a-single-job-in-a-workflow/17234/131), which stores the last run status in cache and then skips jobs based on that status.

**How they used it:**

```yaml
    - name: Set default run status
      run: echo "::set-output name=last_run_status::default" > last_run_status

    - name: Restore last run status
      id: last_run
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: |
          last_run_status
        key: ${{ github.run_id }}-${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.node-version }}-${{ matrix.webpack }}-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ github.run_id }}-${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.node-version }}-${{ matrix.webpack }}-

    - name: Set last run status
      id: last_run_status
      run: cat last_run_status

    - name: Checkout ref
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_dispatch.ref }}

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      if: steps.last_run_status.outputs.last_run_status != 'success'
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
```

[Here is the original workflow file](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/blob/f8305c26997bae8ef0f5dfa52540d842451b4090/.github/workflows/examples.yml).